# Angular 10 + SCSS: Browser not requesting fonts when using @font-face

Tags: css, angular, sass, fonts

I have an Angular 10 app that uses SCSS. I have declared some `@font-face` declarations in `_typography.scss` referring to the fonts in my `assets/fonts directory`. However, when running the application, the browser does not even initiate the request to download the font files.

Following is the style directory:

[image]

This is my `_typography.scss`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan';
    src: 'assets/fonts/Spartan-Medium.ttf' format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan';
    src: 'assets/fonts/Spartan-SemiBold.ttf' format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan';
    src: 'assets/fonts/Spartan-Bold.ttf' format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

I am `@import`-ing this inside my main `styles.scss` file:

```
@import 'reset';
@import 'variables';
@import 'typography';
@import 'utilities';

body {
    font-family: 'Spartan', 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Only `Segoe UI` system font is getting applied. The browser is not even initiating the requests for the font files:
[image]

I then tried preloading my fonts in my `index.html`, and the browser did make the requests, but the fonts were not applied.

Can someone point out why this is happening?

P.S.: Here is my `assets` folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Did you add your fonts to the angular assets? and the path is correct?

Comment: @AliKianoor I have added the structure of my `assets` folder. The path I have provided seems correct since the preload requests actually work, although the browser still doesn't apply the fonts.

Even if the path was incorrect, at least the request could have 404ed, but the request did not even initiate. Also, I looked at the built CSS. The `@font-face` rules are present in the compiled CSS.

Comment: Check your assets in angular.json and make sure you already add the assets folder over there like this:  "assets": [   "src/assets", ],

Comment: @AliKianoor Yeah, the "assets" list seems fine:
`"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just moved across from less to sass and the fonts were not requested.

After a lot of messing about I figured out that it didn't work with **sass** when font-face was declared inside my html tag. It was working before this with less.

```
  // not working
  html {
   font-face: ...
   ...
  }

  // working
  font-face: ...

  html {       
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but in my case my fonts were overwritten by angular material theme.
U can check that by looking at computed styles in devtools. If that is the case then creating custom typography for angular material is recommended.

Comment: I think Ashwin is teaching everybody this